# Having 3 or more columns in select statement for selecting tables doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the `select` method and I want to select multiple columns. It works with 2 columns but more than that it doesn't work. How can i fix it? The code is in a Model.

```
users = User.select(first_name, middle_name, last_name, email, position, 
        gender, address, sss_number, tin_number, phil_health, emergency_name,
        emergency_contact, birthdate, date_hired, department) if (first_name || last_name || position ||
        gender || address || sss_number || tin_number || phil_health || emergency_name ||
        emergency_contact || birthdate || department).present?

return users
```

form

```
<%= form_for @filter do |f| %>
    <h3><i>Please select a column to filter</i></h3>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :first_name, {}, "first_name" %>
        <%= f.label "First Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :middle_name, {}, "middle_name" %>
        <%= f.label "Middle Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :last_name, {}, "last_name" %>
        <%= f.label "Last Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :email, {}, "email" %>
        <%= f.label "Email" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :position, {}, "position" %>
        <%= f.label "Position" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :gender, {}, "gender" %>
        <%= f.label "Gender" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :address, {}, "address" %>
        <%= f.label "Address" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :sss_number, {}, "sss_number" %>
        <%= f.label "SSS Number" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :tin_number, {}, "tin_number" %>
        <%= f.label "Tin Number" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :phil_health, {}, "phil_health" %>
        <%= f.label "Phil Health" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :emergency_name, {}, "emergency_name" %>
        <%= f.label "Emergency Name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :emergency_contact, {}, "emergency_contact" %>
        <%= f.label "Emergency Contact" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :birthdate, {}, "birthdate" %>
        <%= f.label "Birthdate" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :date_hired, {}, "date_hired" %>
        <%= f.label "Date Hired" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :department, {}, "department" %>
        <%= f.label "Department" %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Filter" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are there column names set to the variables? Where and how are the variables set?

Comment: column names are set through a form in a checkbox, ill add the code for that form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in the model is basically the same as the following example:

```
User.select(a, b) if (a || b).present?
```

Now let's imaging `a` was `nil` (not checked in the frontend) and `b` was `'foo'`. That would lead to the following line:

```
User.select(nil, 'foo') if (nil || 'foo').present?
```

Because `'foo'.present?` is `true` the `select` method would receive `nil` as an argument.

To solve this issue, store all variables in an array first and `compact` the array to keep only present values:

```
fields = [
  first_name, middle_name, last_name, email, position, gender, address, sss_number, tin_number, phil_health, emergency_name, emergency_contact, birthdate, date_hired, department
].compact

User.select(*fields) if fields.any?
```